# Product.findByIdAndRemove is not a function Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mern

```
    router.delete("/:productId", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const productId = req.params.productId;

        const deletedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndRemove(productId);

        if (!deletedProduct) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "Product not found." });
        }

        res.status(200).json(deletedProduct);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error." });
    }
});
```

It was working, after changing my post method works with multer, it stopped working and giving this error

Comment: Because they renamed it to [`findByIdAndDelete`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndDelete()). You must have upgraded the lib version

Comment: @Konrad Probably some other people will not notice it too, so send an answer so that people like me can see it.

Comment: `findByIdAndRemove` triggered the `findOneAndRemove` middleware which up to V7 was an alias to `findOneAndDelete()`. In V8 they removed it and you must now use `findByIdAndDelete()`  or `findOneAndDelete()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findByIdAndRemove` is deprecated in Mongoose version 8.0.0 and later. Instead, you should use `findByIdAndDelete`